# Difference between Maven and ANT while Test report generation?

Tags: maven, selenium, ant, maven-3, testng

Which is the best and featured way to generate reports either by using Maven or ANT? What are the features and differences ? I am using selenium webDriver with TestNG. By using testNG should I prefer "build.xml" or "pom.xml" ?

Answer (score 0):

Maven and ant are build tools.  What generates the reports is Testng.  So if you use ant or maven, the report generated will still be the same.  You can probably do a comparison between maven and ant as build tools, not as a report generation framework, to pick up the one you find better.  If you might find this any help.. A blog written long back to describe the ecosystem..http://niharikawhatsnext.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/test-automation-to-building-to-execution-to-scheduling-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can use both maven and ANT to produce XSLT reports which uses TestNg generated output.html. Both are mainly used for build purpose not for report generation.

The XSLT reports generated from maven and ANT both looks same. But there are many advantages in Maven over ANT in testing frame works (I am assuming you know what are those). So I would personally prefer Maven. Please go through the below links which you might found helpful.

http://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-ant-and-maven

http://blog.varunin.com/2012/05/generate-testng-xslt-report-using-maven.html